# AWS EC2 import-image: ClientError: Disk validation failed [We do not have access to the given resource. Reason 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an S3 bucket which contains my ova file. The file name does not contain space, etc.
The S3 bucket is in my default region. I have created the role and trusting policy as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-image-prereqs

### Command used:

I call the following command to start the import:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "IBM QRadar CE 733" --license-type BYOL --disk-containers file://containers.json

{
    "Description": "IBM QRadar CE 733",
    "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "LicenseType": "BYOL",
    "Progress": "1",
    "SnapshotDetails": [
        {
            "Description": "QRadarCE733",
            "DiskImageSize": 0.0,
            "Format": "OVA",
            "UserBucket": {
                "S3Bucket": "ibmqradarce733",
                "S3Key": "QRadarCE733GA_v1_0.ova"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Status": "active",
    "StatusMessage": "pending"
}
```

container.json contains:

```
[{
    "Description": "QRadarCE733",
    "Format": "OVA",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "ibmqradarce733",
        "S3Key": "QRadarCE733GA_v1_0.ova"
    }
}]
```

### Progress check

Please note: I have added xxx to the ImportTaskId.
Already after a few seconds in the "Validation"-Phase I receive the error:

```
ClientError: Disk validation failed [We do not have access to the given resource. Reason 403 Forbidden]
```

Here is the full response:
(Please note: I have added xxx to the ImportTaskId)

```
aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids import-ami-0a09ee6b0e35d8ca0
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "IBM QRadar CE 733",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "LicenseType": "BYOL",
            "SnapshotDetails": [],
            "Status": "deleting",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Disk validation failed [We do not have access to the given resource. Reason 403 Forbidden]",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the vmimport policy attached to vmimport role allows access to the S3 bucket containing your .ova files.

If you copied the policy from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-role) verbatim, you will need to edit it to explicitly grant access to your S3 buckets.

This section:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::disk-image-file-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::disk-image-file-bucket/*"
         ]
```

Should become:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ibmqradarce733",
            "arn:aws:s3:::ibmqradarce733/*"
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

give full public access for Bucket & file (object)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).